# Excel VBA script freezes excel after running for a few minutes

Tags: vba, excel

While my code works for 10 loop iterations, it crashes for home = 30 or more. Can someone please provide me with a clue? Even weirder this code used to work fine... and is not working anymore.

Here's the code:

```
Sub datascrap_clean()

'

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim home                As Integer

Dim output_rows         As Integer
Dim output_columns      As Integer
Dim date_columns        As Integer


'Output rows and columns starting values
output_rows = 3
output_columns = 3
date_columns = 8

For home = 3 To 33

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://www.cqc.org.uk/directory/" & Sheets("Output").Cells(home, 1), Destination:=Range("$A$1") _
        )
        '.CommandType = 0
        .Name = "Homes"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With




For x = 20 To 250
    Select Case Left(Cells(x, 1), 7)

    'Is it a score?
    Case Is = "Overall"

        Sheets("Output").Cells(output_rows, output_columns).Value = Cells(x, 1)
        output_columns = output_columns + 1

    'Is it a date?
    'Case Is = "Carried"

       ' Sheets("Output").Cells(output_rows, output_columns).Value = Cells(x, 1)
        'date_columns = date_columns + 1

    Case Else

    End Select

    Sheets(2).Select

Next x

    'Clean sheet
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Delete

    'Reset column count
    output_columns = 3
    date_columns = 8

output_rows = output_rows + 1
Next home



MsgBox ("Done!")
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you tell where in the code it is freezing?  Put in some stops and step through them until you get to the point where the code just seems to quite working.

Comment: That's the thing, it doesnt freeze at a particular point:
- for home = 10 it doesn't freeze,
- for home = 50 it crashes after a while

Comment: So, you can't hit CTRL+Break when it "freezes" and see what part of code it is hung up on?

Comment: control break doesnt work

Comment: Actually I tried on another computer and it gives me a 1004error, pointing to this line in the code: .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

Comment: Change `BackgroundQuery` false.  Run it. Do you still have problems?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with creating QueryTable objects within a loop and having Excel hang at seemingly random times (usually after creating about 15 QueryTable objects). I noticed that the problem did not happen when I was in the VBE debugging and running with breakpoints inserted. So, in addition to deleting QueryTable objects after using them as suggested in a previous answer, I inserted a short delay at the start of my loop:

```
Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
```

Was able to successfully run a case with ~300 QueryTable objects created with no hanging. Yes, a kludge, but it least provides a work around. Without the delay, I still got Excel to hang even after deleting the QueryTable objects.